# How to post cyrillic symbols in WINDOWS-1251 with OkHttp library?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I'm trying to post field with cyrillic symbols in WINDOWS-1251 in my android application. Currently I have:

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
    .add("login", user)
    .add("pass", password)
    .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT)
    .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
    .url(URL)
    .post(formBody)
    .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
String responseBody = response.body().string();
```

What do I need to add to be able to use CP1251 encoding for those fields?

Comment: 'field with cyrillic symbols'. Where do you have that field which does not contain utf ?

Comment: I don't need UTF. As I said, I need WINDOWS 1251 encoding.

Comment: Yes. But Android uses utf. If you have an EditText, type cyrillic in it and get the text out of it you get utf-8. So thats why i want to know where you get the 1251 text from. Explain better what you have to start with..

Comment: I get string from EditText.

Comment: It could be helpfull if you told something more. What kind of server do you have? Is it php? Can you edit the php?

Comment: `RequestBody formBody`. Show what you do with formBody later,

Comment: Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT)
                .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
                .url(URL)
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

Comment: Request is to PHP script. I cannot change it.

Comment: `Request request`. Show what you do with `request`. Put all code in your post. Not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try to include in your request a `Content-Type` header, along with the proper charset:

```
.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=WINDOWS-1251")
```

See [RFC2068 14.18](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2068/rfc2068.txt).

Comment: Added `.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=WINDOWS-1251")`. It didn't help.